# Failed on Migration using Paperclip on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to install Paperclip using Rails 6.1

I ran this command : `rails g paperclip Model image`

And i got this migration :

```
class AddAttachmentImageToExercises < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :exercises do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :exercises, :image
  end
end
```

But i got this error :

```
Caused by:
StandardError: Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:
```

Then i put class AddAttachmentImageToExercises < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
I got this error :

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
```

What should i do? Thank You

Comment: But why? Paperclip is deprechiated and the authors recommend using ActiveStorage instead. The last release was more then 4 years ago. I would say you should probally use more up to date tutorials. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/closing-the-trombone

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `up` and `down` be instance methods, not class methods?

So removing the "self." might fix this?

```
class AddAttachmentImageToExercises < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    change_table :exercises do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_attachment :exercises, :image
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it

Comment: still got this error wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)